# Define a branch of $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{z}}$ which is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

I thought that the problem can be reduced by taking a function $h(z) = \sqrt{z}$ and rewrite it like $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{z}} = h(1+h(z))$.
So i can find a analytic branch of $h(z)$. Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a branch cut along the positive real axis $\gamma=[0,+\infty]$ and let $h(z)=\sqrt{z}$ be such that ${\rm im \ } h >0$ on $D={\Bbb C}-\gamma$. Then any choice of $\sqrt{1+h(z)}$ will be analytic (because the domain is simply connected and the image does not contain $-1$ by the choice of the cut $\gamma$).

Comment: how you prove that is analytic:  the domain is simply connected and the image does not contain −1 by the choice of the cut  ...

Comment: it's because $im h(z) > 0$ and $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic there?

Comment: yes, or more precisely since ${\rm im \} (1+h(z)}>0$ and $\sqrt{}$ is analytic here (whatever choice you make for the sign of the square root). The image of the composed map may be chosen e.g. to be ${\rm Re} w>0, {\rm Im}w >0$.